# Accessing webserver remotely (contains tcpdump)

Tags: iptables, firewall, port-forwarding, tcpdump

Total noob here so apologies in advance for missing out any key details.

We have a web server which is accessible locally on 192.168.2.1. It is also accessible locally on 176.XXX.XXX.XXX which is obviously an external IP.

When accessing the external IP remotely, my browser times out, so I'm guessing this is a firewall issue. We have a Billion 7800DXL hosted on 192.168.2.6.

In the Billion admin I can see that there is a virtual server set up for ports 80, 2223 and 3306 on TCP that forward to 192.168.2.1.

Is there something else blocking access? If I've missed out vital details let me know. Also 192.168.2.1 has a Linux firewall so maybe this is the issue?

Running the following `tcpdump -vvv -ni eth0 host 185.186.79.109` on the webserver gives me:

```
15:19:08.111133 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 55, id 28066, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52) 185.186.79.109.50554 > 192.168.2.1.http: Flags [S], cksum 0xb153 (correct), seq 3499157894, win 29200, options [mss 1452,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 9], length 0
15:19:08.111189 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52) 192.168.2.1.http > 185.186.79.109.50554: Flags [S.], cksum 0xb7ce (correct), seq 3334957998, ack 3499157895, win 14600, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 7], length 0
15:19:08.111305 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 255, id 61825, offset 0, flags [none], proto TCP (6), length 40) 185.186.79.109.50554 > 192.168.2.1.http: Flags [R.], cksum 0xf89c (correct), seq 1, ack 1, win 14600, length 0
```

So it looks like my browser (185.186.79.109) can see the webserver (185.186.79.109.50554 > 192.168.2.1) but I'm not sure what the rest means.

Answer (score 0):

My immediate thoughts:

- Can the webserver ping the outside world?
- What does `netstat -rn` on the webserver tell you?

Right now, you've shown that the webserver can send packets inside your network, regardless of which IP address is used, but not that it can send and receive packets from outside your network.